# how do i load an mp4 file with rodio

Tags: rust, mp4, rust-cargo, rodio

while it works with .mp3 it does not with mp4.

```
let file = File::open(path).expect("unable to open file");
let file = BufReader::new(file);
// mp4 crashes in let source = ...
let source = Decoder::new(file).expect("unable to convert file to a 
music file");`
```

my cargo should also be appropriate with:

```
rodio = { version = "0.17", features = ["symphonia-isomp4"] }
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong. do i need to select a specific version or feature on symphonia?

i have already tried getting the error, but all that i get is Unrecognized Format.

Edit to adress comments: I do not want to have to install ffmpeg, in order to get the audio from mp4 files.

The Rodio-github sais: "MP4 and AAC (both disabled by default) are handled only by Symphonia."
That is, why i am using features = ["symphonia-isomp4"]

Unrecognized Format is the exact error, unless you want the backtrace as well
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UEDEuP1O4XSMMwmPXV5dxRnIi713UL05/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue is probably due to MP4 being a video format and MP3 being an audio format.  Perhaps you can isolate the audio out of the MP4 and then use that?

Comment: What exact error message are you getting? Edit your question to include it.

Comment: The `Decoder` documentation says it only supports "MP3, WAV, Vorbis and Flac"

Comment: Though the [m4a example](https://github.com/RustAudio/rodio/blob/master/examples/music_m4a.rs) uses it like you are

Comment: Please add the exact error that is coming through.